# How to get the sum of a column up to a certain value?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet that I am using to try and calculate leveling and experience points. **Column A** has the level and **Column B** has the exp needed to reach the next level. i.e. To get to Level 3 you need 600 exp.

**A   B**
1   200
2   400
3   600
...
99   19800

In column I2 I have an integer for an amount of exp (e.g. 2000), in column J2 I want to figure out what level someone would be at if they started from 0.

Comment: Your example "To get to Level 3 you need 600 exp." is poorly chosen, because 600 is also the number we see against "3" in the table, but that is only a coincidence: one needs 600 because it's 200+400. Using a different level, maybe 4 (requires 200+400+600 points) would be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Using a helper column (for example Z): put `=sum(B$1:B1)` in cell Z1 and drag down. This will compute the sums required for each level. In J2, use the formula

```
=vlookup(I2, {B:B, Z:Z}, 2) + 1
```

which looks up I2 in column B, and returns the nearest match that is less than or equal to the search key. It adds 1 to find the level that would be reached, because your table has this kind of an offset to you: the entry against level N is about achieving level N+1.

You may want to put `0 0` on top of the table, to correctly handle the amounts under 200. Or treat them with a separate `if` condition.

#### Using algebra

In your specific scenario, the point amount required for level N can be computed as

```
200*(1+2+3+...+N-1) = 200*(N-1)*N/2 = 100*(N-1/2)^2 - 25
```

So, given x amount of points, we can find N directly with algebra:

```
N = floor(sqrt((x+25)/100)+1/2)
```

which means that the formula

```
=floor(sqrt((I2 + 25) / 100) + 1/2)
```

will have the desired effect in cell J2, without the need for an extra column and `vlookup`.

However, the second approach only works for this specific point values.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in column J and ddrag down as required. Rounddown(I2,-2) rounds I2 down to the nearest 100. Index match finds a match in column B and returns the value in column A of the matched row.

```
=index(A2:A100,match(ROUNDDOWN(I2,-2),B2:B100,0))
```